# Fast way to evaluate the result of a shift

Tags: language-agnostic, binary, hex, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

If I want to see in fast what is the result of a code that does shifting (left/right) I usually write down the binary representation and do the shifting.
But for e.g. shifts of 4 it is actually faster to do it write the hex representation and move the character/digit 1 place to the left/right?
Are there any other tricks for this?

Comment: Here's a trick: write down the binary representation and then visualize the shifting. Skip writing it. Or take it to the next level: don't even write the binary representation at all, visualize everything. Great for tiny numbers. I don't think this is really a topical question, by the way - this is not a coding problem.

Comment: You could learn a table for the sixteen hex digits and four shifts by heart, like a multiplication table.  Without the trivial zeros it is of size 3 * 15, so that wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @starblue:`four shifts by heart` Which 4? It is shift by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7...31 bits

Comment: @Jim 0, 1, 2, 3, because for multiples of four you can shift hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, shifting 4 bits is removing 1 hex because each hex digit is 4 bits in binary. So shifting 8 bits would be like removing 2 hex, and so on.

If you wanted, you could also do the same type of shift with octal, although instead of 4 bits we would be using 3.

Alternately, if you wish to see the translation in decimal rather than octal or hex, you can view shifting as a way to represent division and multiplication.

With shifting left, you can use x1 << x2 as a form of multiplication by 2^x2.

With shifting right, you can use x1 >> x2 as a form of division by 2^x2. Keep note, this will work for positive numbers, not negative.